# How to make a node group have a value attribute

Tags: shaders

What I am trying to achieve is to have a node group (A material on one object) be able to plug into another material (on the same object) as a sort of mask.

Comment: Can you provide details about what your goal is and where you are now?  In more concrete, less abstract terms?  This question might be too unclear to get any good answers without more info.

Answer (score 0):

Once you created the group hit TAB to open the contents. On the right (T-menu) you will see a group tab, click it and then add an input (+). Under type you can select - among others - shader:
[image]